# Java Code isn't working properly when it should

Tags: java, string, random

So i have been trying to help myself learn Japanese by making a randomizer. When I try to run this code it says there are errors but I've looked through and I can't find any. For some reason it doesn't see that the `Ename` is the same as answer. they are both string variables so I don't understand why it wont work properly.
I would love to learn why it isn't working. Thank you for those more knowledgeable than me.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Game {
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

public int enemyCount = 4; // always need to be one less than the enemy

public String Jname;//Japanese Character
public String Ename;//English Character


public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    new Game();

}

public Game(){

    battleMainMenu();
}

public void RandomEnemy() 
{


    Random random = new Random();

    int rnd = random.nextInt(enemyCount);

    if (rnd == 0)
    {

        Jname= "あ";

        Ename= "a";

    }
    else if (rnd == 1)
    {

        Jname ="い";

        Ename ="i";


    }
    else if (rnd == 2)
    {

        Jname="う";

        Ename="u";

    }
    else if (rnd == 3)
    {

        Jname="え";

        Ename="e";

    }
    else if (rnd == 4)
    {

        Jname="お";

        Ename="o";

    }

    System.out.println("\nYou walk around and encounter a "+ Jname );

}

public void battleMainMenu() 
{
    RandomEnemy();

    System.out.println("\nTo defeat this enemy you must write "+ Jname +"'s name in english. " + Ename);// Enames here for debugging purposes
    System.out.println("Your options are : 'a', 'i', 'u', 'e', 'o' ");
    System.out.println("Type one of the options in lower case. ");

    String answer = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println(answer);
    System.out.println(Ename);
    if (answer == Ename)
    {
        System.out.println("\nCorrect!\n");

    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("\nIncorrect!\n");
        battleMainMenu();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Btw i did convert it to utf-8 so it can show the characters in the console.

Comment: How is this relevant to learning Japanese tho

Comment: I am making it so it randomly gives me a charactor and i answer it in the english letter it sounds like to assist in memorizing so that later i can use it for kanji

Comment: can you post what the error says

Comment: It doesn't give an error. but the    if (answer == Ename)
    {
        System.out.println("\nCorrect!\n");

    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("\nIncorrect!\n");
        battleMainMenu();
    }   //isn't working

Comment: I can't figuere out why

Comment: it keeps saying incorrect when it should say correct i put the Print Ename so i know im inputing the right letters

Comment: Thank you very much. especially for the link. the program now works.

Comment: Yup, compare strings with the use of `answer.equals(Ename)` instead of using `==`

Comment: mark his answer as answered thanks~

Comment: Not related to your primary question, but you should create a single `static` instance of `Random` in your main, and then re-use it.  ***Don't*** create a new `Random` each time you call `RandomEnemy()`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `someSting.compare(otherString)` to compare strings, not `==`.  If you want to know why you have to do so look here: [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

In your case:

```
if (answer.equals(Ename)) {...}
```

Comment: Oh well, i did not see the other 4 comments... :) but here you go.